# Prove that there is a symmetric matrix B, such that BX=Y

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

Let $X,Y$ be two vectors in ${\mathbb C}^n$ and assume that $X≠0$. Prove that there is a symmetric matrix $B$ such that $BX=Y$.

Comment: look for reflection matrix sometimes called householder matrix, then follow it with dilatation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the last answer was not detailed enough, so here is another approach, which is constructive.

Pick some orthogonal matrix $Q$, hence $QQ^T = I$ and build $B$ as $B = Q\Lambda Q^T$, where $\Lambda$ is diagonal with it's entries $\Lambda_{jj}$ still left to determine. Then,

$BX =Y \Leftrightarrow Q\Lambda Q^TX =Y \Leftrightarrow \Lambda Q^TX = Q^TY  $, which component-wise gives you the solution for $\Lambda_{jj}$ as $\Lambda_{jj} = \frac{q^T_jY}{q^T_jX}$. ($q_j$ is the jth column of $Q$).

This is a solution in case you do not mind, that $B\in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$. If you want $B\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, then even if $B$ is not symmetric, it might be impossible. Notice, that the case where $X = \bar{Y}$ provides a counter-example for that.

Comment: Actually you can pick $Q=I$ :-)

Comment: :D, Alright you beat me.

Comment: There is still a problem when one of the entries of $X$ is zero but $X\neq 0$ btw, for instance when $X = (1, 0,\dots)$. I guess you could reduce this to the more general case by using your trick with the Q and show that there it can be chosen such that $Q^T X$ has no non-zero entries.

Answer (score 1):

here is one way solve this. if $y = 0,$ then the zero matrix for $B$ would do. so we can assume that $y \neq 0$ let $$z ={|x| \over |y|} y, \text{ so that } |z| = |x|.$$
the orthogonal projection matrix $$H = I - 2a{\bar a}^T/{\bar a}^Ta \text{ where } a = x - z \text{ and a bar means complex conjugate}$$   you can verify that $H$ is unitary and $Hx = z$  now take a scalar matrix  $D = {|y| \over |x|}.$

the matrix $DH x = y$ and $DH$ is symmetric as you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint 1:** If $X$ has no zero entry, prove that you can find a diagonal $B$ so that $BX=Y$.

**Hint 2:** If $X$ has some zero entries, since $X \neq 0$ prove that you can find some orthogonal matrix $P$ so that $PX$ has no zero entry.

Define $X'=PX$ and $Y'=PY$. Find a diagonal matrix $B'$ so that $B'X'=Y'$ and use 
$$
B=P^{-1}B'P 
$$

Comment: In the second hint, how do you know that the resulting $B$ is symmetric?

Comment: @DimitarM.H. Thank you, fixed it.